# Magento 2 get address extension attribute value in carrier collect rate model

Tags: magento2, checkout, quote, extension-attributes, carrier

I successfully pass the extension attribute value to estimate-shipping-method,like this:

[image]

**etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
        <attribute code="shipping_delivery_date" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="shipping_delivery_date" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

I want to retrieve it in my custom carrier model, but no luck

```
class MyCarrier extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
       $deliveryDate = $request->getExtensionAttributes()->getShippingDeliveryDate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are basically setting the extension attributes on the shipping address object and inside the carrier model you are handling the rate request object - as you can tell, two different objects.

If you check the rate request class `vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address/RateRequest.php` you will see that you don't have a direct way to retrieve data from the shipping address object.

But if you look at `vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php` you will see that at some point there's something like this:

```php
// ...
foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
    // ...
                   $freeShipping = $item->getFreeShipping() ?
                        $item->getFreeShipping() : $item->getAddress()->getFreeShipping();
    // ...
}
// ...
```

so, I'm thinking that the  `$item->getAddress()` thing might lead back to the shipping address object and after that you could check if you can extract the extension attributes from it. I didn't test this, but it's worth a try.

Good luck!

Comment: It works and I understood why. Because any products can have separated shipping details. Multishipping... It is why Magento will create separated shipping address for each product in the cart...